# D3: html input field works only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to include a text input field into my D3 as foreign object. The input field does only show up in Chrome. I've tried to dig deeper into this, but couldn't find anything useful. Any ideas are appreciated.

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpe71cjn/). And this is the code:

```
d3.select("body")
    .append("foreignObject")
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .html("<input>")
    .attr("id", "search");
```

Comment: Shows in FireFox 42, too.  Which browsers are you having problems with exactly?

Comment: Maybe the others recognizes this as faulty, since you apend `<body>` inside `<body>`? Just a thought. Btw, this works in IE too. And Opera. And Safari.

Comment: Actually `foreignObject` won't work in IE, only introduced in [Edge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg124132(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm on my phone right now , so I can't test. I have one suspicion though. My original code renders everything inside a view box . Could that be related?

Comment: Fiddling on my phone. It seems to be view box related. Added a view box to this fiddle and it stops working http://jsfiddle.net/x58wngy2/1/